# Using a beta version of Material-UI for a long-term React web applicationwith a lot of content if beta beta features are a necessity

Tags: reactjs, web-applications, frontend, material-ui, beta

Is using a beta version of [Material-UI](https://material-ui-next.com/) for a long-term vision React web application with a lot of content a good idea if the beta features are a necessity and using a UI library that follows Google's Material Design Guidelines is a requirement.

I looked at alternatives like React-Toolbox, MUI and Material Design Lite and they are close to what we need but a product as big and popular as Material-UI would be preferable, which is why I'm hesitating.

I have been searching for the risks of using a beta version and looked at the 22 pre-release notes of the v1.0.0-betaXX versions of Material-UI and it doesn't seem to be *that* bad, but maybe

1. I could use the stable version v0.20.0 and try to find a way to add the features that I need (flex grid being one of them) and eventually *will* migrate to a newer version of Material-UI (which would also include migrating from react v15 to react v16 because Material-UI v1.0.0 is only going to support React v15 temporarily).
2. I could use the beta version v1.0.0-beta.22 and work around the bugs (if/when I encounter them and if there are any), gradually migrate to React v16 and eventually migrate to a released version of Material-UI v1.0.0.

Either way, I'm thinking the migration from a beta of v1 to a release of v1 will be much easier than migrating from 0.20.0 to 1.0.0, no ? But, at the same time, a beta is a beta, so it,s not a final product and I'm not guaranteed anything.

Comment: Note: This question and its accepted answer have become the basis for the ['Should I start with v1-beta?'](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui#should-i-start-with-v1-beta) section in the official material-ui README on Github.

Comment: Thank you, and after 3 months of development, I definitely do not regret the decision. Anyone starting with MUI should go with Beta. The breaking changes are never too complicated to arrange and are very well documented.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[mui-org](https://github.com/mui-org) is focused on releasing a stable v1 and has an [informal target of early 2018](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/ROADMAP.md#when-do-we-intend-to-release-stable-v1).

There will be breaking changes along the way, but dealing with them will be far easier than porting your application from v0 (or your proposed hybrid solution).

If you choose a specific version of v1 and periodically update, the continual refactoring to account for any breaking changes should be relatively painless. 
 The [release notes](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases) are very good and **always** describe the breaking changes introduced with each release.

Bite the bullet and go for v1.

Comment: ...or v4 (coming soon!)